# I saw him cross the road vs having crossed the road

Tags: grammar

Is here any difference in phrases below:

1. I saw him having crossed the road.
2. I saw him cross the road.
3. I saw him do it.
4. I saw him having done it.

Are these phrases interchangeable?

Answer (score 2):

"I saw him having crossed the road" is not grammatical English. You could say:

> Having crossed the road, I saw him.

Which means "After **I** crossed the road, I saw him." But even that is a bit awkward. In short, 2 and 3 are grammatical and 1 and 4 are not. You can say:

> I saw that he had crossed the road.

This emphasizes that he has finished crossing the road, but now it's no longer clear that you were watching *while* he was crossing.

Comment: Ok, is it possible to say: I saw him having been given the lesson. ? thanks

Comment: No, that's ungrammatical. You could say "I saw him being given the lesson" or "I saw him receiving the lesson".

Comment: Are you wondering about how to emphasize that you saw a completed action versus an action in progress? To go back to the original example, "I saw him **crossing** the road" implies that you saw him in the process of crossing but didn't necessarily didn't see him finish crossing. "I saw him **cross** the road" implies that you saw him finish crossing. In conversation, however, those two expressions are mostly interchangeable.

Comment: @mamster, It should be 1 and 4 is ungrammatical and 2 & 3 are not, right?

Comment: Yes, sorry! Will edit.